# Stop-A-Flat tube for 26 x 2.25 tire

Tags: tire, tubeless, 26-inch

I want buy  [Stop-A-Flat tube](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0127EGQZY) for my tire. Tire size is 26 x 2.25

Closest airless tube what I found, has size: 26 x 2.125

Is suitable that size for my 26 x 2.25 tire ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon web pages says

> Stop-a-flat tubes are "Size Specific" to a tire and care should always be taken when matching the tube to the tyre.

But then

> Please note that the 1.75 sizes will fit a 1.90 standard tire.

So that's confusing. You'd really have to check with the manufacturer,

Bicycle tires vary in actual size for a nominal width specification by quite a lot, so if the solid inner tube needs to exactly fit the inside dimensions of the tire it will be difficult to get a match.

Personally, I would not use a product like this as I suspect they could negatively affect tire grip in a dangerous manner.